# Laravel session data not aging

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not entirely sure the title is correct as I could not yet figure out how I got to this problem.

What I have:

- simple model with 2 fields
- crud controller
- on create / edit I process the data and redirect with some info. info is passed by one of 2 methods:
- - `session()->flash("key","info")`
- - `redirect()->route("route.name.here")->with("key","info")`

I added (to the bottom of my layouts blade file) a line to see what is stored in session hoping I'd get a clue on what's going wrong

```
@dd(session()->all(),session("_flash"),session("key"))
```

What is my actual problem? I get the same info again and again.

- create new instance and flash confirmation to user
- valdiation returns with error message

It does not matter which one happens I get the returned info again on each successive page call. If I do something to get a new message that message replaces the old one and stays with me on every page of my site. (even the home-page that does nothing but give you some "lorem ipsum" text)
If the last info was an error due to failed validation I also keep the old inputs.
The index-page only loads the instances and loads the view file (with the data).
For example switching through the pages of the index file (I am using laravels pagination as found in the docs) and due to the dump output I can see that nothing in "session" changes (that includes the entry with key "_token". I thought this one should change but I currently can't check with a working site). The form to create a new instance (of the model) is included in the index-page (Bootstrap card header with inline form as it only requries 1 field).

What did I already try?

- clear the cache
- delete session files (the get created again)
- restarting apache
- rebooting the server (similar to raspberry pi)

I could not figure out how I fk'd this up and am hoping for some pointers

System:

- PHP: 7.3.0alpha4
- Laravel: 5.6.29
- Session handling: file
- OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

**Edit:**
I was able to check the `_token` key with a different laravel installation and the value changes with every page load. Looks to me there is a problem with session handling but I can't figure out where as it only has partial problems (writing something new to it obviously works but changing seems to run into a problem)

**Edit2:**

- [index + edit methods](https://pastebin.com/AKmiVaaY)
- [imgur - index page including create form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXM1S.jpg)
- [Request used for edit method](https://pastebin.com/vbkPV6ZH)
- [session data output in blade file](https://pastebin.com/bQz6uweK)

Comment: currently (to be sure it's not a problem with permissions) my webserver is running the same user as I am using for ssh. nothing changed :(

Comment: tried using redis as session driver: still no changes. so.... no permission problem. must be somewhere in the code. I don't get where it could be.

Answer (score 0):

as I can show, you are missing some details in session laravel documentation.

first of all, if in your two methods `(create , edit)` you use `redirect` that will be better to use `with` for your flash session message like this example below :

```
 return redirect('route.name')->with('status', 'your message here');
```

for more how with function work please check [redirecting with flashed session data in laravel application](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data)

next, within your blade template, you should create one test on that session variable, if it exists or not and then show up it. this code below will show how to that using the Session laravel Facade :

```
@if(Session::has('key'))
    {{ Session::get('key') }}
@endif
```

you can find how to use session facade if you are curious on [laravel 5.0 session documentation section](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session)

Comment: I tried `session()->flash(...)` because i was missing the info (after redirect in view-file). my test looks exactly like yours (except I'm using the helper function instead of facade - AFAIK it does not make a difference).
My problem lies not with not getting data "flashed" but that the data is not removed after being flashed(I'm not talking about 2 times but x times which means 10 or 100 or more).

Comment: I'm using `redirect()->route('route.name',['param'=>$value])->with('key','info')` because I could not find any hint that I could pass that to the redirect function directly. [Named route docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-named-routes)

Getting to show the data to the user is not my problem. My problem is that I have the code you linked (for showing flash-data) and it shows on **every subsequent pageload** and not just the next.

Comment: can you share please your create and edit methods, I guess you are doing something wrong within them

Comment: here is my [index page](https://imgur.com/a/tKDQKtE)
As I have stated before: create form is part of index page (top right)
And here is a [pastebin of my index and edit methods](https://pastebin.com/AKmiVaaY)